# Error when running protractor... node_modules/q/q.js:155

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am facing below error when running protractor tests, using the latest node version - v5.4.1 and npm version - 3.5.3. I face this problem only on the Build Server(Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.1) but not on my local machine.

I am using a local npm and node installation on server which was done through maven-front-end tools plugin.

```
> [plm@siplmapp01 INT static]$ node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt e2e-test
> >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-qunit" not found. Is it installed?
> 
> Running "protractor_webdriver:modules" (protractor_webdriver) task
> Starting Selenium server
> Shutting down Selenium server: http://localhost:4444
> Shut down Selenium server: http://localhost:4444 (OKOK)
> Restarting Selenium server
> Restarted Selenium server: http://127.0.0.1:4444
> 
> Running "protractor:modules" (protractor) task
> [launcher] Process exited with error code 1
> 
> /data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/q/q.js:155
>                 throw e;
>                       ^
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
>     at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1123:19)
>     at Object.goog.loadModule (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1085:46)
>     at /data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1:6
>     at Object.Context.closure.goog.retrieveAndExecModule_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/_base.js:135:8)
>     at <anonymous>:1:6
>     at Context.closure.closure.vm.createContext.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/_base.js:104:12)
>     at Object.goog.importScript_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:879:9)
>     at Object.goog.importModule_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:900:14)
>     at Object.goog.writeScripts_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1323:16)
>     at Object.goog.require (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:663:14)
> >> /data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/q/q.js:155
> >>                 throw e;
> >>                       ^
> >> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
> >>     at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1123:19)
> >>     at Object.goog.loadModule (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1085:46)
> >>     at /data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1:6
> >>     at Object.Context.closure.goog.retrieveAndExecModule_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/_base.js:135:8)
> >>     at <anonymous>:1:6
> >>     at Context.closure.closure.vm.createContext.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/_base.js:104:12)
> >>     at Object.goog.importScript_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:879:9)
> >>     at Object.goog.importModule_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:900:14)
> >>     at Object.goog.writeScripts_ (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1323:16)
> >>     at Object.goog.require (/data/apps/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/PA-PUT-JOB1/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:663:14)
> Warning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 8 Use --force to continue.
> 
> Aborted due to warnings.
```

The protractor configuration

```
var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
//var HTMLReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
//Specs to run individual tests.
    specs: ['../tests/unit/sandbox-spec.js'],
// To run tests as part of the suites.
    suites: {
        intro: ['../tests/unit/login-spec.js','../tests/unit/plm02TabChecks-spec.js','../tests/unit/sandbox-spec.js'],
        e2e: ['../tests/unit/checkBaseline-spec.js','../tests/unit/plm02-spec.js'],
        smoke: ['../tests/e2e/smoke-tests/baselineSchedule-spec.js','../tests/e2e/smoke-tests/validateBaseline-spec.js'],
        sandbox: ['../tests/e2e/smoke-tests/validateBaseline-spec.js']
    },

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'phantomjs',
        //For Server
        //'phantomjs.binary.path':'node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs'

        // For Local Use
        'phantomjs.binary.path':'C:/Users/taaupsa1/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe'
    },

    framework:'jasmine2',
    onPrepare: function() {
        // implicit and page load timeouts
        browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40000);
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);
        browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
// for non-angular page
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    //        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HTMLReporter({
    //            dest: '../screenshots',
    //            filename: 'my-report.html'
    //        }));

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
      allureReport: {
        resultsDir: 'allure-results'
      }
    }));
    }
};
```

Could any one help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved, I had a global node installation in my server which is an oudated 0.10.x version, Protractor versions greather than 3.0 are not compatible with node versions less than 2.x.x. Upgrading it to the latest version solved the issue